# How to change emmets port settings?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

So my problem with emmets is that whenever I start a live server using the live server extension, emmets stops working.
It sometimes randomly works with certain ports, but stops working if i stop the live server and start it again with the same port as it used to work on.

For example, it did not work with the default port just now (5500), but when it changed to 8389, it works, but when I now stopped the server and started with the port 8389, it does not work anymore.

So my suspicion is that it's conflicting ports, and if anyone knows how to change the port settings for emmets (not live server, I've changed the settings for that to random and certain ports that works, to no avail.) or any solution to this problem in general, it'd be greatly appreciated since I love using emmets!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I don't know what @ShanteshwarInde means here, since you clearly described that you are experimenting with the port settings. However, It is a good idea to take the [Tour] and read [ask] to get started with this community. That said, what do you mean by "it does not work"? Are your processes running? Are there any log messages? What is emmets? Maybe this question is a better fit for https://serverfault.com/?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm quite new to everything still, but emmets is an extension in VSCode that allows you to write shorter abbreviations to make the extension write the code in question for you.

For example, writing w10 instead of width: 10px; for CSS.

There's no log messages as far as I know. 

I'll ask on serverfault.com too, thanks!